# How to centre an equation

Tags: equations, amsmath

When I build and view my equation it is always aligned right

```
\begin{equation} 
$$\textit{N}(\textit{t}) = $\frac{P_o}{\lambda+\rho\varepsilon/\Lambda}$[1-e$^{-t(\lambda+\rho\varepsilon/\Lambda}$)]$$ 
\end{equation}
```

but if I build and view using align*

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align*} 
$$\textit{N}(\textit{t}) = $\frac{P_o}{\lambda+\rho\varepsilon/\Lambda}$[1-e$^{-t(\lambda+\rho\varepsilon/\Lambda}$)]$$
\end{align*} 
\end{equation}
```

the equation is centre aligned, but the format changes and the numerator no longer sits above the denominator and moves to the left.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Why use all those $'s inside the equations?

Comment: `\begin{equation}` puts you in display maths mode, and the `$$` takes you out of maths mode again.  remove _all_ the $ signs from your examples, and report if they (still) don't work.

Comment: Just out of interest, you might want to take a look at the answers to one of my previous questions, because there is a lot of information about controlling the indentation of equations on there http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179922/please-help-me-fit-my-equation-into-my-margins/179931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly nesting structures, and the log file will contain error messages telling you this is happening.

`equation` already puts the contents in math mode, so `$` and `$$` are not needed nor allowed in its contents.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Text.
\begin{equation}
  N(t) =
  \frac{P_o}{\lambda+\rho\varepsilon/\Lambda}
  [1-e^{-t(\lambda+\rho\varepsilon/\Lambda})] 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Similarly `align` is a top level command producing a displayed equation, but now with alignment points between lines (marked by `&`). If you need an `align` structure inside `equation` you should use `aligned` instead.  See the [documentation of `amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for further information and examples.

*Addendum* Your original code has `\textit{N}(\textit{t})` which as egreg points is almost certainly not what you intended.  In math mode letters are automatically in an italic font (actually `\mathit`) and just writing `N(t)` as above will give you better spacing.

Comment: `\textit` is surely wrong, in this case. And probably `P_o` should be `P_{0}`.

Comment: @egreg Agreed - I had overlooked that.  Code and sample output updated.  However I have left the `P_o` as is, only the posted can know what is intended.