# Cannot fit align environment into page even with multiline* or \resizebox

Tags: errors, line-breaking, overflow, aligned

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{latex debugs}
\author{Naitik Mundra}
\date{September 2023}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
        & E(a, b)-E\left(a, b^{\prime}\right) \\
        = & \int\left[A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda)-A(a, \lambda) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right)\right] \rho(\lambda) d \lambda \\
        = & \int\left[A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda)-
        A(a, \lambda) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right) \pm A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda) A\left(a^{\prime}, \lambda\right) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right) \pm A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda) A\left(a^{\prime}, \lambda\right) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right)\right] \rho(\lambda) d \lambda \\
        = & \int A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda)\left[1 \pm A\left(a^{\prime}, \lambda\right) \underline{
            B}\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right)\right] \rho(\lambda) d \lambda - \int A(a, \lambda) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right)\left[
        1 \pm A\left(a^{\prime}, \lambda\right) B(b, \lambda)\right] \rho(\lambda) d \lambda
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Now, when I run this, I get an equation that spills out of the page(document is set to `a4paper`):
[image: Above Problem]

I have tried using multiline* and splitting lines manually using \, but I get an error for undefull hbox or an overfull one with no indication as to where the problem actually lies. While using something like `\tiny` works, it makes the math unreadable.

How can I fix this(preferably by putting line breaks at the `\pm` and `-`) so that the fontsize remains the same?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This isn't a perfect match, but should give you some ideas about breaking long lines: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179922

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko Added the document class, otherwise unchanged. It still reproduces the issue.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, but what exactly does that do? I cannot figure it out. (If it using `align`, already tried that does not work.)

Comment: Do you know `breqn.sty`? The name stands for "breaking equations".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to break up line 3 into three parts and line 4 into two parts. To simplify the aligning of the three parts of the old line 3, I'd embed the material to the right of the integral symbol in its own `aligned` environment.

Separately, I'd also replace all 11 instances of `^{\prime}` with `'` and -- since they don't do anything useful -- get rid of all 15 pairs of `\left` and `\right` auto-sizing directives. In the code below, I've used `\bigl` and `\bigr` directives to increase the sizes of the square brackets.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env. and '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectations operator

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\E&(a, b)-\E(a, b') \\
&= \int\bigl[A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda)-A(a,\lambda) B(b',\lambda)\bigr] 
   \rho(\lambda) \,d\lambda \\
&= \int\bigl[ \begin{aligned}[t]
                &A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda)- A(a,\lambda) B(b',\lambda) \\
                &\pm A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda) A(a',\lambda) B(b',\lambda) \\
                &\pm A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda) A(a',\lambda) B(b',\lambda)\bigr] 
                 \rho(\lambda) \,d\lambda 
              \end{aligned} \\
&= \int A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda)\bigl[1 \pm A(a',\lambda) \underline{B}
   (b',\lambda)\bigr] \rho(\lambda) \,d\lambda \\
&\qquad- \smash[t]{\int} A(a,\lambda) B(b',\lambda)\bigl[1 \pm A(a',\lambda) 
   B(b,\lambda)\bigr] \rho(\lambda) \,d\lambda
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Never thought about nesting the environments. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to break the long lines, I suggest to use two `aligned` inner environments. The staggering will tell your readers how to read the formulas.

Avoid `^{\prime}` not because it's wrong, but because a simple `'` is easier to type and to read in the code.

Also avoid all `\left` and `\right` that in your formulas do nothing useful and add unwanted horizontal space.

Note the `\diff` command that adds the correct spacing in front of the differential and has the additional advantage that if you are forced to use an upright “d” (I fervently hope not), you can simply substitute in the definition of `\diff` rather than chasing the whole document.

Note the small trick in the last line to get the minus sign aligned with the `\pm` signs in the lines above.

It's also best not to split before the first equals sign, if space constraints allow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{latex debugs}
\author{Naitik Mundra}
\date{September 2023}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
E(a, b) - E(a, b')
 &= \int \bigl[A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda)-A(a,\lambda) B(b',\lambda)\bigr]
         \rho(\lambda) \diff\lambda \\
 &= \int \begin{aligned}[t]
         \bigl[ &A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda)-A(a,\lambda) B(b',\lambda) \\
                &\pm A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda) A(a',\lambda) B(b',\lambda) \\
                &\pm A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda) A(a',\lambda) B(b',\lambda)\bigr]
                \rho(\lambda) \diff\lambda
         \end{aligned} \\
 &= \int \begin{aligned}[t]
         &A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda)[1 \pm A(a',\lambda) \underline{B}(b',\lambda)] \rho(\lambda)
         \diff\lambda \\
         &\hphantom{\big[}-
          \int A(a,\lambda) B(b',\lambda)[1 \pm A(a',\lambda) B(b,\lambda)] \rho(\lambda)
                 \diff\lambda
        \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to use `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` also in the last two lines. Your choice.

You *might* use `\resizebox`:

```
\[
\resizebox{\displaywidth}{!}{$\begin{aligned}
        & E(a, b)-E\left(a, b^{\prime}\right) \\
        = & \int\left[A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda)-A(a, \lambda) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right)\right] \rho(\lambda) d \lambda \\
        = & \int\left[A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda)-
        A(a, \lambda) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right) \pm A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda) A\left(a^{\prime}, \lambda\right) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right) \pm A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda) A\left(a^{\prime}, \lambda\right) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right)\right] \rho(\lambda) d \lambda \\
        = & \int A(a, \lambda) B(b, \lambda)\left[1 \pm A\left(a^{\prime}, \lambda\right) \underline{
            B}\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right)\right] \rho(\lambda) d \lambda - \int A(a, \lambda) B\left(b^{\prime}, \lambda\right)\left[
        1 \pm A\left(a^{\prime}, \lambda\right) B(b, \lambda)\right] \rho(\lambda) d \lambda
\end{aligned}$}
\]
```

I used your original code just to make a visual comparison:

[image]

Definitely not what anybody wants to see.

Answer (score 2):

With use of macro `\MoveEqLeft` and math environment `aligned`, both defined in the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{mathtools}  % <---


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft[3]        % <---
E(a, b)-E(a, b') \\
    = & \int\Bigl[A(a,\lambda) B(b, \lambda) - A(a,\lambda) B(b',\lambda)\Bigr] \rho(\lambda) d\lambda  \\
    = & \begin{multlined}[t]    % <---
        \int\Bigl[A(a,\lambda) B(b, \lambda)-
            A(a,\lambda) B(b',\lambda) \pm {} \\
            A(a,\lambda) B(b,\lambda) A(a',\lambda) B(b',\lambda)\pm A(a,\lambda) B(b, \lambda) A(a', \lambda) B(b',\lambda)\Bigr] \rho(\lambda) d\lambda
        \end{multlined}         \\
    = & \begin{multlined}[t]    % <---
        \int A(a,\lambda) B(b, \lambda)\Bigl[1 \pm A(a', \lambda) \underline{
            B}(b', \lambda)\Bigr] \rho(\lambda) d\lambda - {} \\
        \int A(a,\lambda) B(b', \lambda)
            \Bigl[1 \pm A(a',\lambda) B(b,\lambda)\Bigr] \rho(\lambda) d\lambda
        \end{multlined}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicates page layout)